# Product of two quotient map need not be a quotient map

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, quotient-spaces

We know that the product of two quotient map need NOT be a quotient map. Is it any categorical explanation of this counter-intuitive phenomenon?

Comment: Why is it counter-intuitive?

Comment: @LeeMosher The category of topological space is a nice category. The definition of quotient space and product space can be restate in categorical language. Category theory is too nice to accept it. Such "bad" thing is intolerable in some extent, for me.

Comment: @LeeMosher So I want to find a categorical explanation of this thing. Not in the specific category of TOP. .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The underlying phenomenon you're observing is that the composition of a right adjoint (e.g. a product) and a left adjoint (e.g. a quotient map) does not preserve the adjunction. Perhaps this is counter-intuitive to you because left adjoints compose with each other and similarly for right adjoints, but they do not interact nicely in general.

Specifically, a quotient map (depending somewhat on the sense in which you mean the word "quotient" -- but it always refers to some sort of colimit) is a pushout of a map $f:A\to B$ along the terminal map $A\to *$, so maps out of the quotient object $B/f$ correspond to maps out of $B$ such that the subobject indicated by $f$ is sent to a point. But products have a different (dual) universal property. A map $C\to X\times Y$ *to* a product is the same thing as a pair of maps $C\to X$, $C\to Y$.

So the universal property of $(B/f)\times(B'/f')$ has to do with maps *into* the individual objects $B/f$ and $B'/f'$ (about which we can say nothing in general, since these quotient objects are defined by maps out of, rather than into, them), while $(B\times B')/(f\times f')$ has a universal property defined in terms of maps *out of* $B\times B'$, which we don't necessarily know anything about, since the universal property of the product doesn't tell us anything about that. These two objects have fundamentally different universal properties.

Comment: Does adjunct functor(left of right) form Top. to Top. has some interesting properties? Just like preserve (right or left)exactness in R-mod.

Comment: Left adjoints preserve colimits (because colimits are themselves examples of left adjoint functors, and left adjoint functors compose with one another), and dually, right adjoints preserve limits.